# Is there any compiler independent POSIX + C Standard method of flushing the instruction cache?

Tags: c, gcc, caching, posix

I would like a method of flushing the instruction cache similar to `__builtin___clear_cache` in GCC but for clearing the instruction cache independent of the compiler. Is there any POSIX + C Standard compliant way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure POSIX will ever care about something this specific. The same goes for C itself. For example, the C standard doesn't specify a lot of things, like having a cache. Or possibly even instructions for that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no C Standard method of flushing the instruction cache.